# How do I fix incompatible SQL Server version found?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using VS 13 just installed SQL Server 2014 Express, created a new database and when I go to add a new table (inside VS) I get the following error:

> incompatible sql server version found

How do I fix this? Should I find the version required by the VS (if so, how?) and I downgrade to that required version or can I workaround it with SQL Server 2014 Express?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Check the "Target platform:" drop-down in the "Project Settings" tab of Project Properties. If "SQL Server 2014" is not selected, select it. If "SQL Server 2014" is not even in the list, you need to do the next part (#2).
2. Make sure that you have the latest version of SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). VS 2013 Community Edition (if not also other editions) shipped with a version that didn't exactly work ;-).

   You should be able to get this by doing the following:

   - Open Visual Studio
   - Go to the TOOLS menu
   - Select "Extensions and Updates..."
   - Expand "Updates" (left nav)
   - Go to "Product Updates"
   - Select the entry for "SQL Server Data Tools" (or whatever has a similar name)
   - Click the "Update" button within that entry
   - It will download a file to your computer called "SSDTSetup.exe"
   - Run "SSDTSetup.exe" and it will download and install the updated version (as of right now the current version is 12.0.41025)
   - Once it is done installing, close and re-open Visual Studio

   Or you can download it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx (just be sure to get the version that corresponds to the version of Visual Studio that you have).
3. There is a check-box for "Allow incompatible platform" in two places:

   - Debug tab of Project Properties. Click on the "Advanced..." button at the bottom. It will be at the top of the scrollable list.
   - Advanced button (on the right) in the "Publish Database" popup when you go to Publish the project from the Build menu. It will be at the top of the scrollable list.