# How do I fix SQL server incompatibility?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

After installing SQL server from  [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55994), I have the folder "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS" which, according to [File Locations for Default and Named Instances of SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server)[^] means I have the latest 2017 version i.e above 2012.

But the error is impeding me from achieving anything. If I try creating a new database, I get the infamous error "This server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 are supported". I bypassed this tricking visual studio into thinking I'm trying to test my connection but after that, I can't populate the rogue database with tables.

Trying to do this results in abrupt shutdown of visual studio and a request to be debugged. In the error log, I can see the last line read "The target database schema could not be retrieved" which still exposes the illegitimacy of my database. Trying to access that database in Server object explorer also results in the error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object".

Also I purchased a CD Microsoft server R2 2012 but ultimately did not install it because it asked me to backup my drive, I fear it may actually reformat my machine or do something else besides simply installing a server. I'm following the instructions on this thread [How do I fix incompatible SQL Server version found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881388/how-do-i-fix-incompatible-sql-server-version-found) and in the drop-down, I can see version 2012 is there already. I also have the SSDT.exe but when I try installing it, it terminates and the error log states the following "MainViewModel.AddFailedCondition: Error: The current operating system is not supported. This application requires at least Windows 7 SP1 or Windows 8.1 to run" whereas I am clearly running windows 8 os.

So how do I go about getting a compatible server for my visual studio 2012? Or how can fix this current state of affairs?

Comment: Are you trying to create a database via SSMS or Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you tried installing [SSDT 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?  MS only supports the last two versions of SSDT, so you may still run into problems.  SSDT includes [Local Db](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express/).  Local Db is a special version of SQL Server you can use for dev work.  Because it is part of the install there should not any version issues. **EDIT:** Fixed SSDT 2012 link.

Comment: If you're using SQl Server 2017, why are you not using SSMS 2017 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms and SSDT 2017 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt? Both are *free*.

Comment: I'm trying to create the database via the server explorer in visual studio. Ssms has a large size and I'm constrained by bandwidth costs so I got a smaller management app: query express. Seehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170/sql-server-management-studio-alternatives-to-browse-edit-tables-and-run-queries. In my question, I stated the weird issue I'm having with installing ssdt. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: It says you need Windows 8.1 to run the VS installer and then you state you are running Windows 8. Windows 8 is not Windows 8.1. Was that a typo or you actually thinking that Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 are the same versions? If you are on Windows 8, upgrade to 8.1 and install the newer version of VS.

Comment: @Robert not visual studio installer. I'm not installing visual studio. The error was from ssdt.exe installer which requested for windows 7 sp1 or windows 8.1.

Comment: @destination-data I've installed ssdt from the link you provided but I can't find it to launch. I can see it in my installed programs though, but all searches for a program called ssdt, sql server data tools or anything along those lines turns up blank. the only software i found during the search is sql server import and export

Comment: SSDT is a Visual Studio add-in. Not used 2012 in a while but should be the same*ish* to current versions. *Projects* >> *New*. From the template it’ll be under something like Data or Business Intelligence.

Comment: @destination-data there is no such thing. The only new inclusion there is "SQL Server" (SQL Server Database project), which I don't know who is responsible for it as I'm installing a number of random suggestions in my bid to get up and running.

Comment: SQL Server Database Project is SSDT. There should also be two other new templates (one for Analysis Services & one for Integration Services).

Comment: @destination-data Which means it's installed right? Remember it was your 2012 link I used. But when I try creating a table, I get the error "An incompatible SQL version detected". I am also unable to find any other new templates besides the one I mentioned. I eventually downloaded SQL operations studio but much to my horror, I can't use that neither because my mysql knowledge is redundant in that realm

Comment: I don’t have an old 2012 install to test against. It’s possible that VS is trying (and failing) to use the 2017 Express engine, instead of the 2012 LocalDb. Probably easier to install SSDT 2017 or 2015 instead. If you don’t have VS 15/17 it will install a minimal shell that can host SSDT.

Comment: @destination-data why would it be looking for ssdt 15/17 when its own version is 2012? Remember the reason you specifically sent a 2012 link was because visual studio 2012 seemed to be having compatibility issues with newer add-ons. The simplest solution would have been to couple visual studio along with its related data management options. Now I'm frustrated and abandoned a course I was gingerly gobbling. I sincerely appreciate your time. My best bet is to manage SQL operations studio whilst looking for some online tool to convert my mysql queries to mssql