# Fix... An Incompatible SQL Server Version was Detected

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have SQL Server 2019 Express installed on a separate home PC and Visual Studio 2017 Express installed on a different home PC. I added the database connection (from the PC where SQL Server 2019 Express is installed) to my Visual Studio 2017 Express C# project and I can use a DataSet/DataGrid to see the data in one of the tables.

But if I select "Show Table Data" or "Open Table Definition" in Visual Studio 2017 Express, I get an error

> An Incompatible SQL Server Version was detected

The database is on the other PC with SQL Server 2019 Express installed. I want to be able to view the data or change and modify the database from my Visual Studio 2017 Express C# project.

I went to `Tools -> Extensions` and `Updates -> Updates` in Visual Studio, but there are no SQL Server Express updates listed. Please Help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix incompatible SQL Server version found?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27881388/2029983) If not, *why* not?

Comment: No. I followed those steps and doesn't work.